# Invalid property name: flex-basis: 1 0 max-content

Tags: css, flexbox, intrinsic-content-size

I'm applying the `flex` property to to a number of divs on the page, and viewed in Chrome get the following:

[image: max-content fail]

The message on hover is `Invalid property name`.

For what it's worth, my code is as follows:

```
.class-name {
  flex: 1 0 max-content;
}
```

I thought `max-content` was [supported in Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content) so am unsure why this would be the case? My browser's up to date and I get the same problem if I pull this into `flex-basis`.

Any explanations or suggestions greatly appreciated, even (especially) if I'm missing something dead simple :)

Comment: Max content for flex-basis is experimental and not supported by chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Perfect - thanks very much @Pete. If you want to pop that in as an answer I'll accept it. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the browser compatibility chart on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Browser_compatibility), the `max-content` keyword for `flex-basis` is still experimental and not compatible with Chrome